# Calculating overlapping timestamp in tableau

Tags: timestamp, tableau-api

I have data as `session_start_timestamp` and `session_end_timestamp` which logs the session time of the user.  I want to find out total session time of the user which is `session_end_timestamp minus session_start_timestamp` and the user can have multiple sessions simultaneously.  If any of the user session's overlap, I just want to count the common timestamp once and then calculate the total session time of the user. How can I achieve this? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

As this would be at a user level you could drop user_id on row shelf and use min and max for the dates, then pass the dates into calculated field

Use the tableau datediff in a calculated field

[image: tableau calculated field for date difference]

Comment: The Datediff function will give me the duration of the total session including the duration of the overlapped time. I need to find the duration of the overlapped session and then subtract it from the duration of the total session for each user. I tried using lookup to find the next start date so that I can check if the next start date is less than the end date of the current record, but it gives me the next date itself and not the timestamp. Also, how can I group the records by username?